# Select-String showing a line that does not exist on the original output

Tags: powershell

I am trying to discover which IP and interface a Windows machine is using to communicate with another machine.

This is the command that I am executing:

```
Find-NetRoute -RemoteIpAddress 192.168.1.10 | Select-String -Pattern "IPAddress"
```

And this is the response:

```
MSFT_NetIPAddress (Name = ";C?8;@B8:8;::55?55;55;", CreationClassName = "", SystemCreationClassName = "", SystemName = "")
```

I do not understand this output because the output of Find-NetRoute without the Select-String is this:

```
IPAddress         : 192.168.0.100
InterfaceIndex    : 4
InterfaceAlias    : Wi-Fi
AddressFamily     : IPv4
Type              : Unicast
PrefixLength      : 24
PrefixOrigin      : Dhcp
SuffixOrigin      : Dhcp
AddressState      : Preferred
ValidLifetime     : 01:10:34
PreferredLifetime : 01:10:34
SkipAsSource      : False
PolicyStore       : ActiveStore


Caption            :
Description        :
ElementName        :
InstanceID         : :8:8:8:9:55>55;C<8;@B8:8<?>55;
AdminDistance      :
DestinationAddress :
IsStatic           :
RouteMetric        : 0
TypeOfRoute        : 3
AddressFamily      : IPv4
CompartmentId      : 1
DestinationPrefix  : 0.0.0.0/0
InterfaceAlias     : Wi-Fi
InterfaceIndex     : 4
InterfaceMetric    : 50
NextHop            : 192.168.0.254
PreferredLifetime  : 02:00:00
Protocol           : NetMgmt
Publish            : No
State              : Alive
Store              : ActiveStore
ValidLifetime      : 02:00:00
PSComputerName     :
ifIndex            : 4
```

Is Select-String really supposed to work similar to "grep" on Windows Powershell?

Comment: the `Select-String` cmdlet works on STRINGS ... and you seem to have fed it a collection of objects. **that forces PoSh to string-ify the entire collection.** instead, try using `Select-Object` with a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When "Grepping" in PS I tend to lean on findstr.

Try this:

```
find-netroute -remoteipaddress 10.0.0.1 | findstr "IPAddress"
```

For me (thats my gateway IP) it returns:

```
IPAddress         : 10.0.0.136
```

And just an FYI, yes, your syntax gave me the same data from InstanceID.

Comment: It worked! It is strange that, of all the articles that I saw about grepping on Windows, all of them have not mentioned findstr, only Select-String.

Comment: I feel your pain, and glad to help :) Given Lee_Dailey's response, I too learned something today :)

Comment: Note that findstr is case sensitive without the /i option.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from `| findstr /i`, here's another probably not that convenient workaround.  You could shorten -stream to -s.

```
Find-NetRoute -RemoteIpAddress 192.168.1.10 | Out-String -Stream | Select-String ipaddress

IPAddress         : 192.168.0.100
```

You *can* search property names with select-object:

```
Find-NetRoute -RemoteIpAddress 192.168.1.10 | select *address*
```

I wish I could search the property values like this, but unfortunately it doesn't work:

```
Find-NetRoute -RemoteIpAddress 192.168.1.10 | where * -match 192
```

I suppose this works, but it outputs all the properties anyway.  At least it only outputs matching objects.

```
Find-NetRoute -RemoteIpAddress 192.168.1.10 | where { $_ -match '192' } 

[pscustomobject]@{name='joe';address='here'},
[pscustomobject]@{name='james';address='there'} | where { $_ -match 'th' }

name  address
----  -------
james there
```

EDIT:

I came up with a "search-object" script that only returns the properties (and methods) that match, by name or value:

```
# search-object.ps1

param ($pattern)

begin {
  $hash = @{}
}

process {
  $obj = $_

  $obj | Get-Member | foreach name | 
  foreach {
    $name = $_
    $value = $obj.$name
    if ($name -match $pattern -or $value -match $pattern) {
      $hash += @{$name = $value}
    }
  }
  [pscustomobject]$hash
}
```

For example:

```
get-process cmd | search-object cmd


Modules         : {System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule (cmd.exe), System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule
                  (ntdll.dll), System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule (KERNEL32.DLL),
                  System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule (KERNELBASE.dll),
                  System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule (msvcrt.dll)}
Path            : C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
MainModule      : System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule (cmd.exe)
ProcessName     : cmd
Name            : cmd
MainWindowTitle : cmd
```

```
Find-NetRoute -RemoteIpAddress 192.168.1.10 | search-object ipaddress

IPAddress
---------
192.168.0.100
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I *think* is happening.  As @Lee_Dailey states, `Select-String` works with `[String]` instances.  `Find-NetRoute` outputs `[CimInstance]` instances...

```bsh
PS> Find-NetRoute -RemoteIpAddress 192.168.1.10 | ForEach-Object { $_.PSObject.TypeNames[0] }
Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetIPAddress
Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetRoute
```

...so some transformation to `[String]` needs to take place so the text can be searched.  If you run this...

```bsh
PS> Find-NetRoute -RemoteIpAddress 192.168.1.10 | ForEach-Object { [String] $_ }
MSFT_NetIPAddress (Name = ";C?8;@B8:8;::55?55;55;", CreationClassName = "", SystemCreationClassName = "", SystemName = "")
MSFT_NetRoute (InstanceID = ":8:8:8:9:55>55;C<8;@B8:8<?>55")
```

...you get the `[String]` representation of a `MSFT_NetIPAddress` and `MSFT_NetRoute` `[CimInstance]` instances.  If you tack the original `Select-String` command onto that...

```bsh
PS> Find-NetRoute -RemoteIpAddress 10.10.10.10 | ForEach-Object { [String] $_ } | Select-String -Pattern IPAddress

MSFT_NetIPAddress (Name = ";C?8;@B8:8;::55?55;55;", CreationClassName = "", SystemCreationClassName = "", SystemName = "")
```

...you get the original output, which is missing the `MSFT_NetRoute` line.  The CIM class name `MSFT_NetIPAddress` is matched by the pattern `IPAddress`, which is why that line is present in the output.

My first thought was that it is not casting input objects to `[String]` but calling `ToString()` on them, and that is what [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string#inputs) suggests...

> **Inputs**
>
> **System.Management.Automation.PSObject**
>
> You can pipe any object that has a **ToString** method to `Select-String`.

...but if I do that I get different text for the `MSFT_NetIPAddress` instance...

```bsh
PS> Find-NetRoute -RemoteIpAddress 192.168.1.10 | ForEach-Object { $_.ToString() }
192.168.0.100
MSFT_NetRoute (InstanceID = ":8:8:8:9:55>55;C<8;@B8:8<?>55")
```

If you look through that documentation there are some mentions of its similarity to or getting it to work like `grep` and `findstr`.  The issue here, though, is the input text it was searching was not what you thought it would be; the text you saw in your console from a bare `Find-NetRoute` command was not the same text that would get passed to `Select-String` via the pipeline.

By the way, if your intention was to just filter the output down to that first `IPAddress` property that is displayed by `Find-NetRoute -RemoteIpAddress 192.168.1.10` then instead of searching the full text for `IPAddress` you could just "search" for matching *property* (sub)names with [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)...

```bsh
PS> Find-NetRoute -RemoteIpAddress 192.168.1.10 | Select-Object -Property '*IPAddress*'

IPAddress
---------
192.168.0.100
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand what is happening better now. I am more used to the Linux terminal, so the behaviour of Powershell was not making much sense. In Linux, I believe that the outputs of the commands are always strings, not objects. Am I right?

Comment: @RicardoAranha Yes, that's the fundamental difference.